# How to integrate "if" in jquery code

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, responsive-design, screen-size

i use jpreloader (http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jpreloader-a-preloading-screen-to-preload-images/). When the preloading finishes, i call the header to move to the screen and i call the content by fading to the screen.

My header is a fixed div (as a sidebar), so when someone opens my page from a small screen, i would like that after the preloading, it calls a relative positioned div from the top to the screen.

Everything works with my code without declaring the window width but when i try to "handicrafting" the script with an "if", it stops working. 
I do not know anything about javascript, i tried to fabricate the code with some samples but i can not make it work...

**The original javascript which works without window screen declaration :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//If browser is IE8 or older we show IE specific page
if(ie < 9){
    ieMessage();
}

/*
* Call functions when dom is ready
*/
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#header').css("left",-300);
    $('.background').css("left",-1380);
    $('#content').css("opacity",0);

    // Preload the page with jPreLoader
    $('body').jpreLoader({

        showSplash: true

    }, function() {

            $('#header').animate({"left":0}, 1200);
            $('.background').animate({"left":-1080}, 100);
            $('#content').delay(1000).animate({"opacity":1}, 2500);

    });

});
-->
</script>
```

**The code which does not work but what i think it is not far from the truth (i hope) :**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {


    // Function to fade in image sprites
    $('.sprite').fadeSprite();

    // Function to animate when leaving page
    $('.transition, #nav a, #logo, #face a').leavePage();

    $('#content').css("opacity",0);

    if($(window).width() >= 1023){
        $('.background').css("left",-1380);
        $('#header').css("left",-300);  
     }else {
        $('.background').css("top",-500);
        $('#header').css("top",-230);
    },


    // Preload the page with jPreLoader
    $('body').jpreLoader({

        showSplash: true

    }, function() {

            $('#content').delay(1000).animate({"opacity":1}, 2500);
            $('#face').animateHome();
            $('#face').resizeFace();

            if($(window).width() >= 1023){
                $('.background').animate({"left":-1080}, 100);
                $('#header').animate({"left":0}, 1200);
            }else {
                $('.background').animate({"top":-300}, 100);
                $('#header').animate({"top":0}, 1200);
            }

    });

});


</script>
```

**I use the following css :**

```
#header {
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
position:fixed;
width:300px;
}

#header .background {
position:fixed;
width:600px;
height:10000px;
left:-1080px;
top:-150px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(9deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(9deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(9deg);
-o-transform:rotate(9deg);
transform:rotate(9deg);
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
background: #2e3740;
}

@media only screen
and (max-width: 1023px) {

#header {
position: relative;
display: block;
width:100%;
height: 230px;
}

#header .background {
position:relative;
width: 94%;
height:500px;
margin: 0 auto 0;
left: 0px;
top: -300px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(9deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(9deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(9deg);
-o-transform:rotate(9deg);
transform:rotate(9deg);
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
background: #2e3740;
}
}
```

If someone can correct my code...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Change the `{` that closes the `if` to a `}`, that's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, i answered in a comment to Jayantha here below...

Answer (score 1):

your have syntax errors,Try this code, the position of `{` is wrong and the `:` in `css` function shouldn't be there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($(window).width() >= 1023){

        $('.background').css("left",-1380).animate({"left":-1080}, 100);
        $('#header').css("left",-300).animate({"left":0}, 1200);
     }else {
        $('.background').css("top",-500).animate({"top":-300}, 100);
        $('#header').css("top",-230).animate({"top":0}, 1200);
    }

});
```

**Edit**
Not sure what your javascript logic supposed to be doing but you can combine those like this,

```
<script>
if(ie < 9){
    ieMessage();
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($(window).width() >= 1023){

        $('.background').css("left",-1380).animate({"left":-1080}, 100);
        $('#header').css("left":-300).animate({"left":0}, 1200);
    {

    else {
        $('.background').css("top",-500).animate({"top":-300}, 100);
        $('#header').css("top":-230).animate({"top":0}, 1200);
    }

  $('#header').css("left",-300);
    $('.background').css("left",-1380);
    $('#content').css("opacity",0);

    // Preload the page with jPreLoader
    $('body').jpreLoader({

        showSplash: true

    }, function() {

            $('#header').animate({"left":0}, 1200);
            $('.background').animate({"left":-1080}, 100);
            $('#content').delay(1000).animate({"opacity":1}, 2500);

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: However, it does not work... now the header stays on the screen and when i resize the screen to smaller, the header with its bg disappears. My page : www.igorlaszlo.com

Comment: Do i oblige to combine my script to the other one ? Am i obliged to state all css in the script before and after or we declare only the elements which change ?

Comment: you still have `$('#header').css("left":-300).animate({"left":0}, 1200);`

Comment: change it to `$('#header').css("left",-300).animate({"left":0}, 1200);`

Comment: Yes you can get all scripts to one tag, and keep in mind that `$(document).ready(function() {` fires after all document is loaded , that means your css is loaded. No matter where it is placed

Comment: Jayantha ! Thanks, i corrected the ":" to ","... but still does not work... now, 1) the preloader has disappeared, 2) the header background stays on the screen and 3) when i resize the screen, the header does not show up on the screen...
I guess i am obliged to combined my script to the first one, can you tell me how ?

Comment: Jayantha ! I think you did not understand what i really want but does not matter, i tried anyhow your newly edited code, it does not work... please, please, look at my NEWLY EDITED code (in my original question, the code which i try to make working). 
I guess, first i must declare the css "if screen width >= X" and else... then i must declare the animation in both cases (if and else) under the preload anymation... Look at the code pls what i newly fabricated which does not work yet...

Comment: I'm debugging your site now, I see an error in console , can u update the code in your site with new code you had put in the question?

Comment: It is done... so, i wanted to make the same what it is with #content... but must be with an "if" and "else"... 
First the preload should work, then two possibilities : 1) if window >= 1023, header must come from left... 2) else : header must come from up

Comment: Still I see an error , check your browser console(F12 in chrome) then you can fix it easy, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , `

Comment: i opened it with f12 but i can not see the error... where can i find it ? what is unexpected token ? that starts to be chinese for me :))

Comment: If you are using  chrome , press f12 and then go to `Console`, then you see the error. And click on it , you will see your code . :)

Comment: ah, i think i saw something... the sentence you said is marked red just under the first "if-else" statement... i have a feeling that i did not finish my code well with }, ???

Comment: Ok, that was it ! Now i deleted the "," and it charges the elements, but i still have three problems : 1) the preloader has disappeared, 2) the header background stays on the screen and 3) when i resize to smaller screen, the header does not show up on the screen...

Comment: It says now : Uncaught ReferenceError: loop is not defined ... what is it ?

Comment: Sorry, this is not an error of my page but another js code but nothing about my problem... so, do you have still an idea how i should state what i would like to do ?

Comment: I think it's working now, you have a css issue I guess , that is why pre loader not shown. You can debug and see it .

Comment: You are genious ! So... tonight i did not sleep yet + an update closed my window and it closed my style.css with wrong codes + nothing works... so, a lot of problems... 
Now, everything works, excepte the header when i resize... maybe it will be still css problems... i want to thank you that you sacrified a lot of time for me !!! I go to sleep and if i can not find the solution, i come back tomorrow... have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You code that doesn't work has a brace around the wrong way. This probably happened because of the odd syntax shaping you are using; Try this;

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    if($(window).width() >= 1023) {
        $('.background').css("left",-1380).animate({"left":-1080}, 100);
        $('#header').css("left":-300).animate({"left":0}, 1200);
    } else {
        $('.background').css("top",-500).animate({"top":-300}, 100);
        $('#header').css("top":-230).animate({"top":0}, 1200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Another note; Open your debugger console so you can see these errors, it would tell you exactly where this error was.

Comment: Press F12 to open the debugger console. Chrome and Firefox both have awesome dev tools. You should read up about them.

Comment: Thanks ! But Nick, as Jammykam said, there is still an error in the code ( .css("top",-230) )... 
I use Firebug on Firefox to inspect elements but i do not know how to see javascript errors...

Comment: Otherwise set us up a fiddle or link us to the website.

Comment: Thanks Nick ! I edited my question, please look at my new trial code which does not work yet but i guess this will approach to what i want... it does not work yet...

Comment: Sorry, my page is : [www.igorlaszlo.com](http://www.igorlaszlo.com)
First the preload should work, then two possibilities : 1) if window >= 1023, header must come from left... 2) else : header must come from up...

Comment: Ah, okay, did you open your console and see the error it is producing?

Unexpected token :  $('#header').css("left":-300).animate({"left":0}, 1200);

Can you see what is wrong with this?

Comment: sorry, sorry... i updated my page just now with my new trial... you saw the old one... look at it now... but the problem is that i can not use Firebug for script errors because i do not kbnow how it works. and also i am quiet weak in javascript

Comment: Well you NEED to be able to look at the console for javascript errors. Either google/youtube how to use firebug or use something more simple for the moment, like the developer console for Chrome. Do this and you will see where the error in your Javascript is.

Comment: Ok, i found an error, i deleted a "," and it does not show more error but still : 1) the preloader is disappeared and 2) when i resize to smaller screen, the header does not show up on the screen...

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, it was also a css problem... now, only the resize question has left... i will see it tomorrow !

Comment: It works perfectly for me! Small screen size I see the loader, and then the header drops in from the top, and large screen size I see the loader and then header comes in from the left :)

No worries! Have fun in that javascript console!

Comment: At first load 1) large screen loads perfectly 2) small screen does not load the header (name and icons), only the header bg... 3) at large screen load and then screen resize from large to small, the header and the header bg do not show up... gggrrr, i am not at the end yet :) but it will be tomorrow... i really go now :)

Comment: Okay! If you are still struggling submit another new question tomorrow, as this is no longer relevant here. Cheers!